# I'm from India, planning to do Phd in Marketing Management. Can I pursue it with my job thats 5 days a week 10 hours a day?

Tags: phd, job, part-time, management

I am currently working in the media industry having a 9 years experience. I want to do a Phd in order to get into the academics sector in the next 3-4 years maybe. I have a 5 days a week working schedule. I have researched a bit regarding the same and found out that some UGC approved universities offer part time Phds. Will that be advisable? Also, will I be able to complete it in 3 years? I cant afford to leave my job since I have a lot of financial responsibilities. Thanks in advance! Waiting in anticipation.

Comment: Most full time PhDs take at least three years, so expect a part time PhD to take much longer than that: at least double the time.

Comment: My intuition and the comments on [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/141253/112007) suggest that this will be really hard. 50 hours/week of work won't leave you much time to do your PhD. The university might raise that objection too... though I am not familiar with the situation in India.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 3):

Anything is possibly, but a PhD is a full-time occupation, so holding a job that demands fifty hours on-top seems infeasible. Even for a part-time PhD, you'd be working a *lot* of hours.

(Assuming a part-time PhD plus a full-time job is equivalent to a full-time job with fifty percent more in overtime is a fallacy in my mind. As is assuming two part-time jobs are equivalent to one full-time job.)